# Ui-bootstrap-dialog closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

To close modal window one should call function modal.close(result).

```
close(result) - a method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result
```

What is result here?

What is the difference between close(true), close(false), close('blah-blah')>

Comment: you can return the result of the items in the modal dialog if you need it in another controller

Comment: what items? Can you give me an example?

Comment: The docs examples show that close resolves the modal instance `result` promise. This basically is a way to pass data back to the original caller of the modal service from the modal controller. Inspect the example script and play with it in the plunker link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you close the modal with *something* :

```
close(something)
```

You can get this *something* in the promise `$modalInstance.result`:

```
$modalInstance.result.then(function (something) { 
    // ... 
}
```

See ui-bootstrap modal **[documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)** and **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sdKphmYGUvzXOM1fFyEz?p=preview)** for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your result of an operation at the modal back to the controller.

```
 modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

Look at this plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5eL3qSGnb4T9gkUU6PgT?p=preview)