# Angular modal- the modal is displayed from the start and I can't hide it

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular js
I have to open a modal dialog which display some selected value.

Open Modal

```
    <div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>E{{inputValue}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The controller for the module which contain the modal is:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap.modal']);
   app.controller('ctrlTags', function($scope){
       $scope.inputValue=$('input:checked').val()
       $scope.open = function() {
           $scope.showModal = true;
           return $scope.inputValue;
       };

       $scope.ok = function() {
           $scope.showModal = false;
       };

       $scope.cancel = function() {
           $scope.showModal = false;
       };
    });
```

For some reason the modal is displayed as is it is a regular part of the page (doesn't function as a modal)

Comment: At first the you should correct the name of the dependency module.Use `ui.bootstrap` instead of `ui.bootstrap.modal`.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan- it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling a boolean is not how `ui-boostrap` modals are opened. See [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). Basically you have to call `$uibModal.open` with a template:

```
$scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });
}
```

Have a look **[at this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/13tooLQTRE2sP5sAoHlw?p=preview)** where I'm passing a value to the modal, through the `resolve` property of `$uibModal.open`.

Comment: Michael P. Bazos- if I need to return some values?

Comment: From the controller of the modal, pass some data to the `close` function. Then get this data with `$modalInstance.result.then( ... )`.

Comment: Michael P. Bazos- what should I write in the then()....sorry I'm new in angular.js

Comment: A function with one parameter. This parameter is the data you pass to the `close` function. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32979819/3120193)

Comment: can you demonstrate it in your plunker. I didn't understand if I need to put$modalInstance.result.then( ... ) in the ModalInstanceCtrl or the other one

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. You should mark this one as solved and open another. I'll see what I can do.